# Cmake execute process with mutiple inputs and outputs

Tags: file, cmake, arguments, command-line-interface

I want to run multiple command line tools using cmake eg:`execute_process`, give `execute_process` 3 inputs "file paths" and receive 3 files as output and then use each of the 3 output files as another tool's input.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just use **separate** `execute_process` for every command. What is a problem with that approach?

Comment: Can I give execute_process 3 inputs "file paths" and receive 3 files as output  and then use each of the 3 output files as another tool's input ?
if so please give me an example

Comment: "use each of the 3 output files as another tool's input?" - If another tool accepts paths to the input files, then just pass these paths: `my_tool <file1> <file2> <file3>`. Please, provide an example (description) of the tools involved. Otherwise, it is unclear what do you want and what is your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Tsyvarev.
I have 3 exe files. I need to execute the first let's call it X1 with 3 text files as arguments, then X1 will produce 2 text files (T1,T2).
X2 will take T1 as an argument and execute and ouput  2 text files 
My question is Can you give me an example of how to do this using cmake ?

Comment: The first call could be implement like `execute_process(COMMAND /path/to/X1.exe file1 file2 file3)`. For other calls use similar approaches.

Comment: Can I specify where the output files of the process would be ?

Comment: It depends on your executable only. If that executable allows specification of output files, then you could pass these parameters. If the executable doesn't allow specification of output files, then you cannot pass these parameters. Still, the problem stated in the question post is **unclear**.